# How do I style an embded PowerBI dashboard?

Tags: css, iframe, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have managed to embed a PowerBi Dashboard into a webpage.

Unfortunately, it looks hideous. For example, the padding is ridiculous; The title is stuck in the top-left corner, which I'd like to remove; all the content is loaded into an iFrame, which if I do not set the height and width, makes the dashboard near-invisible and non-responsive (in terms of window scaling); nothing is centred...

I have tried overriding the CSS. For example, I tried to set the `display: none !important;` property on the header (to remove the title), but it has no effect. I also tried changing the background color of the iFrame from grey to match the color of the webpage, but that too did not work.

Does anyone know how I can style my PowerBI dashboard and embed it without an iFrame (is this even possible?)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, at the moment, it's not possible to embed anything from PowerBI to a web page without an IFrame.

Do you really need a dashboard, maybe a report would do it? At least you'd be able to place the components as you like.

Comment: Yeah, I embedded the report instead, but the iframe is hideous... I have no control over the CSS or position of the elements. I don't want to have to embed each element separate as I would then have multiple iframes, wouldn't I?

Comment: You're right, it's not pretty but it works. I guess you're not able to gather all the visuals to a single page and embed only that one report?

Comment: All my visuals are in 1 report, but I'd like to have control over the padding, margins, fonts, etc. When it's in an IFrame, the limit is the cross domain origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I managed to use CSS to re-style the iFrame for both reports and dashboards.

I'm using an angular project and added the CSS to my component that is displaying the Iframe.

```
border-width: 0; //Removes Iframe horrible border
```

I also adjust the height, width and position.

If you struggle to find what element to change the CSS, use the inspect element in Chrome and test by changing some CSS on each element.

I was able to hide and change the position of the title when I found what div it was in with:

```
visibility: hidden; //true to show
text-align: centre; //left or right
```